# Linear Matrix Inequality - "HOW TO"

Tags: matrices, linear-matrix-inequality

I have a tough time understanding how to use Linear matrix Inequality to solve simple inequality problems. I would appreciate a simple "How to" on the following examples.

$$ \bar PA + A \bar P - W^TB^T - BW + \sigma I + \bar P^2 \lt 0 $$

- $P$ is unknown matrix $m \times m$ (semi definite)
- $A$ is known m*m matrix (representing dynamics of a LTI system)
- $B$ is known $m \times 1$ vector
- $\sigma$ is unknown scalar
- $I$ is the $m \times m$ identity matrix
- $W$ should be unknown as well (?)

My question is, how to make it into a matrix, regarding Linear Matrix Inequality. The result is shown below, I would like to know, how to get there from the above mentioned inequality.

$$\begin{bmatrix} \sigma  I + \bar P A + A \bar P - W^T B^T - BW &&& \bar P\\ \bar P &&& -I\end{bmatrix} \lt 0 $$

Another example:

- inequalit:

$$ W^TW \le c_1I $$

- the LMI matrix is then:

$$\begin{bmatrix} -c_1I & W \\ W^T & -I\end{bmatrix} \lt 0 $$

One more example:

- inequalit:

$$ c_2^{-1}I \le \bar P^2 $$

- the LMI matrix is then:

$$\begin{bmatrix} - \bar P & I \\ I & -c_2 \bar P \end{bmatrix} \lt 0 $$

All I need is a simple explanation, how to go from one to another. I see some pattern, but I would like to make sure, or I would like to understand how to do it (not just guess).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The repeating pattern in all these approaches is an attempt to get rid of the quadratic terms in order to obtain the LMI's. This is possible through  [the Schur complement approach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_complement). Specifically, the following equivalence holds
$$M>0 \quad and \quad M-X^TR^{-1}X>0 \Leftrightarrow \left[\matrix{M & X^T\\X & R}\right]>0$$